# Zero-shot Text Classification With Generative Language Models

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I know many of the new generative LLMs (GPT, LLama, Falcon, etc.) are used  for zero-shot classification. I don't understand on a detailed level how this is supposed to work.

For example, if i had a question like:
`query = "... Answer with yes or no. Answer: "`. Would i use something like `res = model(query)`

And then compare if the token for yes or the token for no are more likely?
This seems like a very crude approach that could be improved.

How is this done properly?

Thanks for the answers :)